# Placeholder not showing for date field

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

Date input field is not showing placeholder on my android device, although it showing on the browser.

```html
<label class="item item-input">
              <input type="date" placeholder="Start date"  ng-model="localPlacementStep.starts_at">
            </label>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi you can check value of variable "localPlacementStep.starts_at" in your controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.dateclass{
width:100%;
}

.dateclass.placeholderclass::before{
width:100%;
content:attr(placeholder);
}

.dateclass.placeholderclass:hover::before{
width:0%;
content:"";
}
```

And add the class in your html

```
          <input type="date" class="dateclass placeholderclass" placeholder="Start date"  ng-model="localPlacementStep.starts_at">
```

You can remove the placeholder by

```
ng-click="$(this).removeClass('placeholderclass')"
```